# js issue in client validation registration

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I'm having a problem with file that I created ( reg.js ) for client side validation. In fact, I want to echo out the errors if new user try to submit his credentials without filling all the input fields needed(Firstname, Lastname, email and password)

I'm getting this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljuma.png)

I'm pretty new in PHP and this is my first project for a simple C.R.U.D. web site and I'm stuck with this, I tried to google it, but I couldnt find similar solution so I can't really figuire it out how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Those are linting errors, not script errors. If jQuery has been imported into your page, the script should at least start to run - it will recognize `$` and `document`.

But there's another problem: `hmtl` is not a jQuery method. You probably meant to use `.html`

Comment: I did include it on my index page with help of : <script src="./js/reg.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

### The IDE doesn't always know what will be available/defined in a web environment

In your code, the IDE has problems with two variables: `document` and `$` - that is simply because they aren't defined anywhere *in your own code*. However, neither of them are supposed to be defined by you: `document` is a standard JS variable available in every browser and referencing the current document, and `$` is just an alias for `jQuery` which is probably included in a separate file.

Just make sure you include the jquery file before your own so that the variables are defined by the time your script gets interpreted.

Try running your code in a browser to test it, the dev console is a lot more helpful than any IDE for debugging JS.

Comment: I included the jquery file before my own code on index.php 
Here's the picture: 
[link] https://imgur.com/a/Nb51i [link]